# storage for global variables during destruction or unload

Tags: c++, static, global-variables, destructor

I m not clear if the storage for static global variables can ever be reused or released, especially after global destructors for other objects are called.

If in one file i have:

static int a; //assume value of a will change sometime during the program

int getA() { return a; }

And in another file:

extern int getA();

class B {

public:

```
~B() { if (getA() ==..... }
```

};

static B b;

Is it always safe to refer to getA() in ~B() (considering order of global destructors may be undefined between translation units) or can the storage for "a" be released or reused by the runtime at some point?

I know that during initialization for global variables there are 2 phases, static and dynamic, during static phase their memory is filled with 0s and during dynamic phase constructors are called.  Is there anything like that in reverse for finalization and unload?

Does C++ standard say anything about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The brief answer is no. It's part of the .data or .bss sections of your program.

Of course, it can be reused "illegally" if you know the address and want to use the space. But it is always there otherwise. From start to finish.

Answer (score 0):

> I m not clear if the storage for static global variables can ever be
>   reused or released, especially after global destructors for other
>   objects are called.

If you mean the memory storage, it is never 'released'(unmapped from the process memory space)

> Is it always safe to refer to getA() in ~B() (considering order of
>   global destructors may be undefined between translation units) or can
>   the storage for "a" be released or reused by the runtime at some
>   point?

Yes. int a is POD and it doesn't have ctor.

> I know that during initialization for global variables there are 2
>   phases, static and dynamic, during static phase their memory is filled
>   with 0s and during dynamic phase constructors are called. Is there
>   anything like that in reverse for finalization and unload?

From a program's view, you may just ignore the static phase. the 'unload' you mentioned is usually done by kernel. In Linux it's in in exit_group/_exit system call

Comment: An object being POD does not mean you are allowed to access its contents after it has been destroyed.

Comment: it would not be 'destroyed'. the .bss section is there when your program is still running

Comment: please show me where in the C++ standard it says that "static POD objects do not get destroyed, as they are in the .bss section". (Hint: it doesn't. You are talking about implementation-specific behavior. From the language's point of view, once an object is destroyed, it is destroyed, and the optimizer is free to assume that destroyed objects are... destroyed. Invalidating assumptions made by the optimizer can lead to "fun" behavior in your code.

Comment: :). calm down.  if you are talking about standard, there is no need to   mention optimizer anyway. I am not sure how 'destroyed' is defined in the c++ standard. some other may give constructive answers as regard to that.

Comment: I checked c++98 and here are some except:

    3.7.1  Static storage duration
    1 All objects which neither have dynamic storage duration nor are local have static storage duration. The storage for these objects shall last for the duration of the program (3.6.2, 3.6.3).